# how to add width attribute for jQuery prompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to add 75 % width for one prompt, not for all prompt. How to fix this?

JavaScript file prompt:

```
if (id == 'finalDestination' && data[1] !== undefined && data[1] !== "" && data[1] !== null) {
  $.prompt("<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>INTERNAL REMARKS FOR FD " + destination + "</span>" + "\n" + "</br>" + data[1]);
}
```

Comment: Add the link to the plugin you are using please. You will need to add an id for the prompt you want to target in order to make each one unique.

Comment: is it bootstrap prompt or anything else please describe all things here

Comment: jquery/jquery.js,jquery/jquery.util.js,jquery/jquery.preloader.js,jquery/jquery.centreIt-1.1.5.js,alert/jquery-impromptu.3.2.js,/alert/congAlert.css,js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js,autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js,js/calendar/datetimepicker_css.js

Answer (score 4):

you can use like this

```
$.prompt("<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>INTERNAL REMARKS FOR FD  </span>" + "\n" + "</br>",{ position:{width:100}});
```

Comment: Not Working Jinesh

Comment: For this link, it is working fine. in my application its not working. anyhow thank you for your help

Comment: http://49.204.83.102:8082/logisoft/                                                                                                                              User name - Kuppu , Password - 123456 , Steps to enter above alert page -> after login to application click Exports-> LCL-> Quotes,Booking,BL -> click  New Bkg button, after that enter origin CFS Miami, enter  destination Kingston. now that above alert will show, above alert. the filename is lclExportBooking.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158138/discussion-between-jinesh-and-kuppusamy-k).